# Getting 'Namebox' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef error when trying to render a react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm learning react and I'm stuck on this issue. All I want to do is to render a component which resides in the current Class. When I run this code I'm getting an error .

This is the Code.

```
class NamesBox extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    Namebox(props){
        return(
          <div>
             <div>{props.name}</div>
           </div>
        );
    }

    sayHello() {
        let names = ["joseph",'john','megha','nadhiya'];
        return names.map(name => {
            return (
            <Namebox name={name} key={name}/>
            );
        })
    }


    render (){
        return (this.sayHello());
    }

};

export default NamesBox;
```

> Failed to compile ./src/NamesBox.js   Line 21:5:  'Namebox' is not
>   defined  react/jsx-no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Can you also add code for Namebox component? how are you importing the Namebox in Namesbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`namebox` is a function not a component. You are trying to invoke it inside the `sayHello` function as a component. Try `this.namebox(name)` instead. You are not suppose to create a component within a component so `namebox` is just a function and it should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Thanks . I got it ! :)

Comment: Can you tell me from where do I learn the basics which covers things like this?

Comment: I would suggest you look into online coursea like code academy or udemy outside of that it helps to read the documentation. Go to reactjs.org this is a good starter resource I found there https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/